# TypeError: Failed to fetch in Swagger

Tags: post, swagger

I want to map the photo to the server by using POST via http, but I get an error "TypeError: Failed to fetch" . Why can this be?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gYzG7.png)

Comment: Welcome, please read [this guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) on how to ask a good question on SO. You will need to edit this question if you want people to spend time answering it.

Comment: What is the error message in the browser console? What is the `host` used in your spec? If you are using SwaggerHub - what is the value of the Routing option at the bottom-right of the Swagger UI panel - "routing via proxy" or "routing via browser" (see https://i.stack.imgur.com/JFCoA.png)?