# Swagger produces "Auth ErrorTypeError: Failed to fetch" when authorizing

Tags: c#, azure, oauth-2.0, swagger, authorization

I have followed roughly [Scott's blog](https://www.scottbrady91.com/identity-server/aspnet-core-swagger-ui-authorization-using-identityserver4) in combination with [Joseph's blog](https://www.josephguadagno.net/2022/06/03/enabling-user-authentication-in-swagger-using-microsoft-identity). Unfortunately, I get the error *Auth ErrorTypeError: Failed to fetch*.

The config for authorization is like this (`{tenantId}` is a valid GUID).

```
services.AddSwaggerGen(options =>
{
  options.AddSecurityRequirement(new() { ... });
  options.AddSecurityDefinition("oauth2", new()
  {
    Type = SecuritySchemeType.OAuth2,
    Flows = new()
    {
      AuthorizationCode = new()
      {
        AuthorizationUrl = new("https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenantId}/oauth2/v2.0/authorize"),
        TokenUrl = new("https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenantId}/common/v2.0/token"),
        Scopes = new Dictionary<string, string>
        {
          { "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default", "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default" }            
        }
      }
    }
  });
});
```

Then, I also have the config for the UI like so ({clientId} is a valid GUID).

```
app.UseSwaggerUI(options =>
{
  options.OAuthAppName("Beep");
  options.OAuthClientId("{clientId}");
  options.OAuthClientSecret("HakunaMatata");
  options.OAuthScopes(["https://graph.microsoft.com/.default" ]);
  options.OAuthUsePkce();
});
```

The authorization button in Swagger opens the popup and when requesting the call, the error above is returned. I don't understand where the problem occurs nor how I can troubleshoot it further. The only thing I noticed was that not providing any scopes, leads to an error message in Azure. Providing a scope won't even show the sign-in page there. I've verified that the .[well-known](https://login.microsoftonline.com/a2728528-eff8-409c-a379-7d900c45d9ba/v2.0/.well-known/openid-configuration) produces correct values for authorization and token endpoints. I verified that the secret is correct for the app registration as well as the Redirect URI pointing to my Swagger (https://localhost:7001/swagger/oauth2-redirect.html). Most of the related questions deal with implicit flow or API key, which isn't applicable in my case. Similar questions regarding the error message are [rather](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55339189/typeerror-failed-to-fetch-in-swagger) [not](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44285007/swagger-typeerror-failed-to-fetch) [rewarding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56568703/swaggertypeerror-failed-to-fetch). I also tried to declare a dedicated scope (api://d53180a4-0a79-4f7a-96aa-3f2eed32f559/SwaggerScope) and using it shows me the login page but picking a user produced the same error message.

I inspected the network calls and noticed something unexpected. Apparently, CORS is triggered on the token endpoint **and** it also reports 404 Not Found (which is self-contradictory but I imagine the not-find-ness is somehow caused by the CORS-ness). The URL **is not** what I specify in my config above (according to the [.well-known](https://login.microsoftonline.com/a2728528-eff8-409c-a379-7d900c45d9ba/v2.0/.well-known/openid-configuration) endpoint) and I don't control the server to activate the allowed origins.

[image]
What can I investigate or try out?

Comment: I used this [code](https://i.imgur.com/Cw3lwxl.png), and able login without any [issue](https://i.imgur.com/iWleN6X.png)

Comment: @AsleshaKantamsetti Both of those links produce 404 Not Found for me.

Comment: Have you used single page application for Swagger app registration?

Comment: @AsleshaKantamsetti Yes. In fact, I tried both Web and SPA. I think it's some kind of misconfiguration with the token endpoint. It's start to look like it's PICNIC here.

Comment: Instead of placing secrets, such as AuthorizationUrl and TokenUrl, in Program.cs, put them in appsettings.json.

Comment: I also placed the values in Program.cs and got the same [error](https://i.imgur.com/g1vwBEw.png).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created this project using Swagger UI Authorization for ASP.NET Core API, and it was successfully authorized without any errors.

Below is the code I used for Swagger UI Authentication.

```cs
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen(
    o =>
    {
        o.SwaggerDoc("v1", new Microsoft.OpenApi.Models.OpenApiInfo { Title = "Swagger Azure Ad", Version = "v1" });
        o.AddSecurityDefinition("oauth2", new OpenApiSecurityScheme
        {
            Name = "oauth2.0",
            Type = SecuritySchemeType.OAuth2,
            Flows = new OpenApiOAuthFlows
            {
                AuthorizationCode = new OpenApiOAuthFlow
                {
                    AuthorizationUrl = new Uri(builder.Configuration["SwaggerAAD:AuthorizationUrl"]),
                    TokenUrl = new Uri(builder.Configuration["SwaggerAAD:TokenUrl"]),
                    Scopes = new Dictionary<string, string>
                    {
                        {builder.Configuration["SwaggerAAD:Scope"],"Access API as User" }
                    }
                }
            }
        });
        o.AddSecurityRequirement(new OpenApiSecurityRequirement
        {
            {
                new OpenApiSecurityScheme
                {
                    Reference=new OpenApiReference{Type=ReferenceType.SecurityScheme,Id="oauth2"}
                },
                new []{builder.Configuration["SwaggerAAD:Scope"]}
            }
        });
    });
var app = builder.Build();
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI(
        o =>
        {
            o.OAuthClientId(builder.Configuration["SwaggerAAD:ClientId"]);
            o.OAuthUsePkce();
            o.OAuthScopeSeparator(" ");
        });
}
```

Below is my complete Program.cs class.

**Program.cs**:

```cs
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Options;
using Microsoft.Identity.Web;
using Microsoft.OpenApi.Models;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApi(builder.Configuration.GetSection("AzureAd"));
builder.Services.AddControllers();
builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen(
    o =>
    {
        o.SwaggerDoc("v1", new Microsoft.OpenApi.Models.OpenApiInfo { Title = "Swagger Azure Ad", Version = "v1" });
        o.AddSecurityDefinition("oauth2", new OpenApiSecurityScheme
        {
            Name = "oauth2.0",
            Type = SecuritySchemeType.OAuth2,
            Flows = new OpenApiOAuthFlows
            {
                AuthorizationCode = new OpenApiOAuthFlow
                {
                    AuthorizationUrl = new Uri(builder.Configuration["SwaggerAAD:AuthorizationUrl"]),
                    TokenUrl = new Uri(builder.Configuration["SwaggerAAD:TokenUrl"]),
                    Scopes = new Dictionary<string, string>
                    {
                        {builder.Configuration["SwaggerAAD:Scope"],"Access API as User" }
                    }
                }
            }
        });
        o.AddSecurityRequirement(new OpenApiSecurityRequirement
        {
            {
                new OpenApiSecurityScheme
                {
                    Reference=new OpenApiReference{Type=ReferenceType.SecurityScheme,Id="oauth2"}
                },
                new []{builder.Configuration["SwaggerAAD:Scope"]}
            }
        });
    });
var app = builder.Build();
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI(
        o =>
        {
            o.OAuthClientId(builder.Configuration["SwaggerAAD:ClientId"]);
            o.OAuthUsePkce();
            o.OAuthScopeSeparator(" ");
        });
}
app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();
app.MapControllers();
app.Run();
```

I placed values such as ClientId, TenantId, AuthorizationUrl, and TokenUrl in appsettings.json instead of placing them in program.cs.

**appSettings.json**:

```json
{
  "AzureAd": {
    "Instance": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/",
    "Domain": "<YourDomain>.onmicrosoft.com",
    "TenantId": "<YourTenantID>",
    "ClientId": "<ClientId>",
    "CallbackPath": "/signin-oidc",
    "Scopes": "access_as_user"
  },
  "SwaggerAAD": {
    "AuthorizationUrl": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/<TenantId>/oauth2/v2.0/authorize",
    "TokenUrl": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/<TenantId>/oauth2/v2.0/token",
    "Scope": "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default",
    "ClientId": "<ClientId>"
  },
```

For the Azure AD API App Registration, the redirect URL is placed in the web application as shown below.

[image]

For the SwaggerAAD App Registration, I placed the RedirectUrl in the Single-page application as shown below.

[image]

I took the endpoint values from the Swagger client app registration.

[image]

I have added the following API permissions below.

[image]

When I placed authorizationUrl and tokenUrl in Program.cs, I received the error below. So, I put these values in the appsettings.json file.

[image]

After putting the authorizationUrl and tokenUrl in the appsettings.json file, I received the output below without any errors.

**Output**:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Wt-actual-f...?!